# How to validate selected value from many dropdown select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Example we have this 3 select tags.

- select#1 -> Audi
- select#2 -> Saab
- select#3 -> Audi

so how to check validate all selected value from all select tags while we update it or select it ? and how to prevent it from submit?

[image: this is the sample of validate that was duplicated with other select tags]

#### HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: by validate you mean, checking duplicate selections in 3 dropdowns?

Comment: Presumably you'd need to write some JavaScript to do this.

Comment: @PEJK yeah, i want to check the duplicate value

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `this` for getting the validation part. First get the new value which is selected then check with other `select` tags for their values if it match then trigger duplicate.

Here is a sample [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbx3c8tc/)

```
$("select").change(function(){
var newVal = $(this).val();

$(this).siblings().each(function(){
if($(this).val() == newVal)
{
alert("duplicate");
}
});

});
```

-Help :)